# CSS3 Transition: Animate child to 100% width, parent jumps to 100% width instantly

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to create a delete button, that once you click it, expands to show the delete option, so you won't delete anything by mistake. The problem is that the parent container jumps to full size right away while I would like it to grow gradually.

This can be overcome when I set the fixed pixel width for the parent container, but the problem is that I don't always know the width of the contents. Therefor I used a percentage to get it dynamic.

I don't really know how to explain it clearly so I've made a fiddle to show you: http://jsfiddle.net/cgHcP/

HTML:

```
<div class="right">
    <div style="background-color: #000; display: inline-block;">
        <div class="roll-button">
            <div class="icon">x</div>
            <div class="text">Remove</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #000; display: inline-block;">
        <div class="roll-button">
            <div class="icon">x</div>
            <div class="text">Remove</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Roll Button */
div.roll-button {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: width .5s ease-in-out;
}

div.roll-button .icon {
    left: 0;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #ff3e3e;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: .7;
}

div.roll-button .text {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    height: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #ff3e3e;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 0 0 0 24px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

div.roll-button:hover .text {
    padding: 0 5px 0 29px;
}

div.roll-button:hover .icon {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
}

div.roll-button:hover {
    width: 100%;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 200px;
}
```

When you look at the fiddle, you'll notice the parent container (black), jumps to full size when hovered. Even though the child seems to grow gradually. This behavior causes trouble when you put multiple items inline (like in the fiddle, and exactly what I want to do).

I'm, trying to make this button purely with CSS, but this is where I get stuck. Does anyone have a suggestion how this can be done by using purely CSS?

Comment: I see now that It only works well in chrome for me. Safari doesn't work properly. In safari it highlights the animation to 100% width problem. Can I animate from fixed width to 100% width or auto? The problem seems to be solved when I set a fixed pixel value for widths. For an altered version with fixed widths (that seems to work well), see this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cgHcP/2/. The problem is that I can't use fixed widths, because the contents are dynamic, so therefor the width should be dynamic.

Comment: I was just going to mention that - the problem is going from px to % width.

Comment: I guessed so. So there is no way to get this to work without using javascript? I can always use javascript to calculate the width of the contents and set the width of the parent to fixed pixels. I only hoped it to do without using javascript. I've tried using animating the max-width property, but this gives issues width animations. If the max-width is bigger than the element width, it will start animating the element from the start. If the max-width is 150% of width, the transition will start 1/3 later. Thank you for your reply though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick to achieving what you want is using `width:auto` on the `.text` and limiting the `max-width` of it.. the [new working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgHcP/6/)

```
div.roll-button .text {
    width: auto;
    max-width:0px;
}

div.roll-button:hover .text {
    max-width:100px; /* set this to the maximum allowed value.. */
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. The problem is that I don't know how wide the child element (the text label) would be. I had hoped to solve this without using javascript, but that seems to be a tough nut to crack if even possible at all at this moment.

Comment: @mrcrazylee I might have missed the problem.. isn't it working fine on the jsFiddle in my answer?

Comment: Your fiddle works like a charm. Because it is set to fixed pixels. The problem is that the text label can differ. When I change the length of the text in the button, 75px is not enough. See for example my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cgHcP/4/. I can't set fixed pixels because I don't always know how big the text label in the button will be. As I said before, I can probably solve this using javascript to calculate the width of the contents and then set the parent to that width. My goal was to do that by using purely CSS. I guess that's not really possible.

Comment: I forgot to mention this in the question itself, I only added that as a comment, my mistake!

Comment: Thanks for your updated fiddle! I have tried it that way too, but I am too much of a perfectionist for this method I think. The problem now is that the animation is not completely fluid. I would like the rotation of the X to start and stop at the same time as the text-label. The only way is to use a transition to width 100% or auto to make the transitions work as I want to. At least until webkit provides support for transitioning to auto width. I will go for a jQuery / CSS3 combination to set the width in real pixels by calculating the width of the contents. I will update the result.

Comment: See my updated fiddle for my solution using jquery. It just seems too much of a hassle (if even possible at all) to do it without the use of javascript. Many thanks for your help though. It guided me to this result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seemed to much of a hassle to get this to work without using javascript, so I decided to go the javascript way using jQuery.

I now set the width in real pixels to bypass the problem that still occurs in most browsers when you make a transition from a pixel width to auto or percentage. I did it by creating a wrapper element with a overflow:hidden and summed up the width of the children. This sum I used to set the button width in real pixels.

Furthermore i've added a timer to close the button within a preset amount of time. My idea for this button was to not have to show a delete dialog asking if the content should really be deleted. Maybe this fiddle will be useful to someone else.

Check my latest fiddle for the [final result](http://jsfiddle.net/cgHcP/7/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="roll-button">
    <div class="icon">x</div>
    <div class="label">Short Label</div>
</div>
<div class="roll-button">
    <div class="icon">x</div>
    <div class="label">This is a very long label</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #ff3e3e;
}

.roll-button {
    margin-right: 12px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.roll-button  .icon {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.roll-button .label {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 5px;
}

.roll-button.open .icon {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
}
```

**javascript/jquery**

```
$(function() {
    $('.roll-button').bind('click',function() {
        var iconWidth = $(this).find('.icon').outerWidth();
        var newWidth = 0;
        var timer = [];
        var $elm = $(this);
        $(this).children().each(function(){ newWidth += $(this).outerWidth(); });
        if(!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).addClass('open').css({'width':newWidth+'px'});
            setTimeout(function() { 
                $elm.removeClass('open').css({'width':iconWidth+'px'});
            },5000);
        }
    });
});
```